# How to create dynamic html with dynamic component in Angular 10?

Tags: html, angular, angular-dynamic-components, dynamic-html

I've read carefully about these questions: [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960) and [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular)

And I tried to understand the code in [this woring plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wh4VJG?p=preview&preview) mentioned in these questions. But this plunker cannot be opened anymore.

In my case, I need to generate html dynamically, and in the generated html, it also need to generate components dynamically.

I created a single select with options like this:

```
<option>aaa {SingleSelect} bbb {text}</option>
<option>aaa {AutoComplete}</option>
<option>aaa {SingleSelect} bbb {text} ccc {MultiSelect}</option>
```

***{...}*** means a dynamic component, For the first option, if this one is selected, I should replace **{SingleSelect}** with s single select component, and replace **{text}** with a input text. For the rest like `aaa` `bbb`, it's just simple text, should be displayed as label.

So if I select the first option, it's view should be the same like the following code:

```
<div>
  <span>aaa</span>
  <SingleSelect></SingleSelect>
  <span>bbb</span>
  <input type="text>
</div>
```

**What I have done:**
I created a directive to generate dynamic component, the dyrective takes a param as Input, if the param is SingleSelect, it will return a SingleSelectComponent.

**The problem I have**:

I can only generate dynamic component, but how to apply the generated component into a dynamic html?

I tried to use [innerHtml], but since innerHtml can only use static value, inner html with dynamic component seems not work.

A simple example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-inueit?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Can you create your demo code on stackblitz.com and let me know. I can take a look and see how we can help

Comment: @ShashankVivek I've edit it.